# Is there a music app that lets me start/pause playback by tapping anywhere on screen?

Tags: iphone, applications, software-recommendation, music

I'm looking for an iOS app where, once the music is playing, I can touch anywhere on the screen to pause it, and then start it again.

Comment: Are the earplugs an option? If you click on them, the music will stop?

Answer (score 1):

The [CarTunes Music Player](http://cartunesapp.com) app does what you need - there are no buttons, just taps and swipes for all music controls.

Tapping is play/ pause, swiping is next/ previous track etc. Even volume can be adjusted by holding and dragging up/ down.

The app is not free at the moment but does fluctuate in price and is sometimes even free, as can be seen in the App Activity sidebar on [App Shopper](http://appshopper.com/music/eyedrive)

Answer (score 1):

[Beat Music Player](https://itunes.apple.com/ph/app/beat-music-player/id605037069?mt=8) is free at the moment and uses a double tap anywhere on screen to start/stop music

[LeechTunes LT](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/leechtunes-lt/id348689070?mt=8) is also free and a single tap starts/stops playback (there is a paid version as well)